# Group count product ids in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I am fairly new to sql so I apologies for if this is a nooby question but I have been racking my brain for a while and search google with no answers so this is my last resort.

I have been trying to make a top selling page on my personal site which sells the top selling item for the last 30 days.

Withing the database there are 2 tables for this: products and products orders

The products how total sales of all time, review count of all time and other relevant information but the product orders have the product sale date.

So the way I see it the only thing products is good for is the title, image and price.

So I now look at the products orders and this has the product id and the date sold.

So my question is how to i group the ids,

for instance if I had:

```
productid = 42, datesold = 2013-11-08 21:11:10
productid = 11, datesold = 2013-11-08 21:09:10
productid = 42, datesold = 2013-11-08 21:06:10
productid = 2,  datesold = 2013-11-07 21:11:10
productid = 11, datesold = 2013-11-06 21:11:10
```

How would I return it so it basically says

```
productid = 42 (sold 2 times)
productid = 11 (sold 2 times)
productid = 2 (sold 1 time)
```

Can something like this even be done?

Also I think I have the left join which shows it but still cant get the logic on the group counting

Here is my left join logic, please bare in mind it will be pdo, this is just showing the query before I prepare statement it ;)

$todaysdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("now - 30 days ago"));

```
SELECT * FROM product_order LEFT JOIN product ON product_order.productId=product.id
WHERE product_order.modifiedDate >= $todaysdate AND product_order.status = 2 
ORDER BY product_order.modifiedDate DESC;
```

Thanks in advance for any help given :)

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Ive changed it but for some reason its throwing up a major error:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '15:14:13 AND product_order.status = 2 AND product.status = 1 GROUP BY product_o' at line 4
Stack Trace:

Here is the sql query:

```
$todaysdate = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime("now - 30 days ago"));

SELECT product.id, product.name, product.picture, product.mainImage, product_option_detail.price, COUNT(product_order.productId) AS NumberOfOrders FROM product_order 
RIGHT JOIN product ON product_order.productId=product.id 
INNER JOIN product_option_detail ON product_order.productId=product_option_detail.productId 
WHERE product_order.modifiedDate >= {$createddate} AND product_order.status = 2 AND product.status = 1  
GROUP BY product_order.productId
ORDER BY NumberOfOrders DESC;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its MySQL

Comment: Please understand that your update is a completely different problem from what you asked initially. You can use a static value as the query argument to verify that your query works correctly. When you have verified that, please mark the correct answer as accepted and post a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` to group the rows by the id and name of the product and use the `count` aggregate to count the number of orders for each product.

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(po.order_id) 
FROM product_order as po
LEFT JOIN product  as p ON po.productId = p.id
WHERE po.modifiedDate >= $todaysdate AND po.status = 2 
GROUP BY p.id,p.name
ORDER BY po.modifiedDate DESC;
```

more about group by http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, count(po.order_id) AS ProductSold 
FROM product_order as po
LEFT JOIN product  as p ON po.productId = p.id
WHERE po.modifiedDate >= $todaysdate 
GROUP BY p.id,p.name
ORDER BY ProductSold DESC;
```

Comment: please refrain from posting the same answer if you do not provide any additional information.